# pinch zoom in scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, pinch

i am making a single view app, within a scrollview which contains a UIImageView, as the image view is a magazine page, all i need to do is to make it possible to zoom properly on it and scroll, so i set up the zoom by tapping (thanks to the apple's tapToZoom sample) and everything works great.

the problem is that i want to include the zooming by pinch which is a little bit harder to implement, i succeeded but the zooming is not that proper, it seems like it's jumping scales, also when i zoom out, the imageView can go so little that it's not visible anymore?

you can have a look to the controller here:

https://github.com/HosniD/pinchzoom-iphone/blob/master/scroll/scroll/TestViewController.m

Does anyone have an idea about how to make it better?

Comment: why do you have a handlePinchGesture? this gesture is already handled in the scroll view,

Comment: what do you mean? what do i have to do then?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from apple documentation

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

    return self.imageView;

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;

    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;

    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);

    self.scrollView.delegate=self;

}
```

[Check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877807/pinch-to-zoom-effect-on-uiimageview-inside-scrollview/20321643#20321643)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is in this [PhotoScroller demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) written by Apple. I've used that myself and it works perfectly.

Check out the ImageScrollView module in particular. It handles zooming.

Here's the code from UIScrollView's header about zooming:

```
/*
 the following properties and methods are for zooming. as the user tracks with two fingers, we adjust the offset and the scale of the content. When the gesture ends, you should update the content
 as necessary. Note that the gesture can end and a finger could still be down. While the gesture is in progress, we do not send any tracking calls to the subview.
 the delegate must implement both viewForZoomingInScrollView: and scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale: in order for zooming to work and the max/min zoom scale must be different
 note that we are not scaling the actual scroll view but the 'content view' returned by the delegate. the delegate must return a subview, not the scroll view itself, from viewForZoomingInScrollview:
 */

@property(nonatomic) float minimumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0
@property(nonatomic) float maximumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0. must be > minimum zoom scale to enable zooming
```

Comment: actually that's a cool way to do it but seems a little bit complicated compared to what i did, also i don't see the instructions he used to set the gesture recognizer on the viewmImage, how does it come?

Comment: It does it by setting the maximumZoomScale and minimumZoomScale properties of UIScrollView. I edited my answer.

Comment: that's what i did at the of my viewDidLoad...did you look at my code?

Comment: Are you sure maximumZoomScale is greater than minimumZoomScale?

Comment: i am pretty sure it is, minimumZoomScale is about 0.6

Answer (score 0):

Use my demo application for guidance: http://rexstjohn.com/facebook-like-ios-photo-modal-gallery-swipe-gestures/.

Includes support for storyboards and autolayout.