# how to Zoom image using CABasicanimation

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

how can I write this using CABasicanimation.

Answer (score 2):

below is the simple implementation

```
-(void)StartAnmation {
          [subview.layer addAnimation:[self ZoomAnimation] forKey:@"Zoom"];
}

-(CAAnimationGroup *)ZoomAnimation {
    CAAnimationGroup *ZoomAnimation = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    CABasicAnimation *In = [self zoomIn];
    ZoomAnimation.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: In, nil];
    ZoomAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
    return ZoomAnimation;
}

    -(CABasicAnimation *)zoomIn {
CABasicAnimation *ZoomInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        ZoomInAnimation.beginTime = 0.0f;
        ZoomInAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0];
        ZoomInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        ZoomInAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
        return ZoomInAnimation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Zoom images you can done by using UIImageView itself.

Please refer the answer [Pinch To Zoom Effect on UIImageView inside scrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877807/pinch-to-zoom-effect-on-uiimageview-inside-scrollview/20321643#20321643)